# Wordpress [Gravity Forms – Signature Add-On] Signature box not working, “Uncaught type error”? -

Tags: wordpress, forms, signature, gravity, typeerror

I'm using Gravity Forms on my (Wordpress) website for some simple forms, and have installed the signature add-on to require people to sign their name before being able to submit the form.

At first everything was working perfectly, but at some point in the last few months (possibly after switching hosts), the signature add-on function stopped working.

You're supposed to be able to draw in the signature box (to sign your name), when you hover over the box the mouse turns into a pen tool. The mouse still turns into a pen, but now the box is not interactive - clicking and dragging does not produce any marks.

Using inspect element on the page, I can see the following error message: 

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

This error does not appear on pages without the signature add-on. Here is a page featuring a form with the add-on at the top:

http://northeastpcg.com/test-for-forms/

Does anyone have any insight as to what the problem might be? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you do any research on that error? It's pretty clear if you had that the error is indicating that jQuery isn't loaded on that page.  If I inspect the code, I see that jQuery is loaded, but it's loaded too late (jQuery should be loaded BEFORE the ss.js code).  So - check your GravityForms - it has a setting for jQuery "no conflict" - try fiddling with that.  If that doesn't work, contact GravityForms for support.

Comment: Thanks so much, it seems the "no conflict" mode was already turned on (though there wasn't anything specifically referencing JQuery). Is there any easy way to load jQuery earlier on the page?

Comment: @AndrewCoCo, did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue and it's driving me insane.

Comment: @GregBurkett in this case it happened to be a conflict with another plug-in I was using. I used a debugging plug-in to test one-by-one all of my plug-ins and determined it was one that added a smooth scroll transition to anchor links - though I'm not sure what specific line of code had the conflict. I just deleted that plug-in and it worked fine after.

Comment: THANK YOU for the info... Really appreciate you sharing what you found. This actually helped me solve my own problem, and lo and behold it was a smooth scroll issue as well! :)